# Changing plain additions and subtractions to checked ones in a large codebase

Tags: java

We have a large code base with a lot of long arithmetic code in various parts of it. Unfortunately it sometimes overflows silently which are really hard to debug. In a few places we've changed these to Guava's [LongMath](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/LongMath.html) checked* methods but doing it all places needs too much work.

Is there a way to easily change these plain long add and subtract operations to `checkedAdd` and `checkedSubtract` which we could use in our test systems?

(I guess we would also be happy with an existing byte-code magic library or a tool which operates on source code level as well.)

Comment: Please mind that requesting off-site resources like libraries is off-topic on Stackoverflow. So you should edit your question a bit, so it won't get closed.